# Extract mismatched fields in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given a dataset like this -

```
const data = [
  {type: 'text', field: 'name'},
  {type: 'minMax', minField: 'min', maxField: 'max}
] as const;
```

How would I extract all the fields as a type? e.g. *'name' | 'min' | 'max'*

At the moment I'm doing this but it doesn't scale -

```
type fields = Extract<typeof data[number], {name: string}>['name'] | Extract<typeof data[number], {minName: string}>['minName'| 'maxName']
```

Comment: Are the objects in that array going to be all different?

Comment: Assume types of 'text' and 'minMax' only

Answer (score 0):

We need to iterate over each object type in the array, omit the key "type", and the find the values types of each object.

```
const data = [
  {type: 'text', field: 'name'},
  {type: 'minMax', minField: 'min', maxField: 'max'}
] as const;

type Data = typeof data;

type KeysValues<T> = T[keyof T]

type ExtractFields<D extends Readonly<any>> = D extends readonly [infer T, ...(infer R)]
  ? KeysValues<Omit<T, 'type'>> | ExtractFields<R>
  : never

type Fields = ExtractFields<Data> // 'name' | 'min' | 'max'

let test: Fields = 'name'
test = 'max'
test = 'max'
test = 'somethig else' // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvKATwAcBTALhgHIpSAPKKgGhgDMBLUgGzkqrAQBbUlQC+THPiJk+g9mACyCOsxhywAMU49Z81YOVbuvagZWisAXRgIIMUJCgBuLFmmkYAESQp07kKzwPi5uJB4A0qSEEABqCFwArqQQADwAKgB8aDBpGADWUQE5lq7uMACiDABOCMBQRjypnjD0tGBwdgBKpAhw4FyEKQhghBlZ6M2tpO12VT19YAOY8qykVTksAHTbABQrazCdAJQluAD8MJHRcYnJKQDyclDpLDRhVGMwAD4V1bX12g6KU6GUklDApAAbmtSmEYA0OtlKlAanUEU0fFkAPRY6gCYRUb6mPREqhmKiuLikWC0aCUdHZfhCERuZKwdBk5QU2ns0xc1nQRkQEDCKAAC3YAHMWlwICIYDiWlUqiAqlggA)